# Reducir posición del borde de un elemento sin alterar su contenido

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Actualmente estoy haciendo pruebas muy simples para testear nuevas formas de dar estilo al contenido utilizando bootstrap.

Tengo dos elementos maquetados de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="prueba.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus ex explicabo alias illo, nulla atque sed a aliquam veritatis consectetur eveniet eaque deleniti, distinctio repellat mollitia quaerat! Consequuntur, quidem cum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="prueba.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus ex explicabo alias illo, nulla atque sed a aliquam veritatis consectetur eveniet eaque deleniti, distinctio repellat mollitia quaerat! Consequuntur, quidem cum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.row{
     border:2px solid black;
     margin:40px!important;
 }
```

Vista previa:
[image: vista_previa]

Mi pregunta es la siguiente; ¿Como podría reducir el borde de cada fila sin alterar el contenido de las mismas?, el resultado que busco sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: padding negativo quizá? En row deifne `padding` con un valor negativo: `-20px;`

Comment: La propiedad `padding` no admite valores negativos, quizás porque su función principal sea únicamente extender el contenido de un elemento. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Creo que no tendrás mas remedio que colocar un div encima.

Comment: ¿Qué debe ocupar el ancho del contenedor?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No se sí es exactamente a lo que te refieres, pero debe ocupar el 100% del ancho, es decir, las 12 columnas del grid de bootstrap.

Comment: Me refiero a: Es el borde el que se mueve o Es el contenido de dentro? Aparte, creo que se podría hacer sin necesidad de agregar un nuevo div, usando pseudo clases. Cuando llegue a un ordenador lo pruebo.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Debería moverse sólo el borde, ya que el texto tiene un pequeño margen por defecto y pienso que no sería necesario añadirle más. Lo que principalmente busco es que la imagen quede por fuera del borde.

Comment: Preguntaba porque en las imágenes que compartes, parece que el borde se mantiene (ocupando el 100% del ancho) y son las celdas las que crecen excediendo el borde

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Espero haberlo aclarado entonces, ¡gracias por tus respuestas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes obtener este efecto usando pseudo elementos como `::before` o `::after`. La idea sería mover el borde al pseudo-elemento y hacer que este ocupe el 100% el contenedor (menos el margen que quieras dejar) posicionándolo de manera absoluta sobre el `row`.

El código sería algo como esto (tienes que darle a "Página completa" para verlo bien):

```css
.row{
     position:relative;
     margin:40px!important;
 }

.row::before {
    content: "";
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    display: table-row !important;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus ex explicabo alias illo, nulla atque sed a aliquam veritatis consectetur eveniet eaque deleniti, distinctio repellat mollitia quaerat! Consequuntur, quidem cum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus ex explicabo alias illo, nulla atque sed a aliquam veritatis consectetur eveniet eaque deleniti, distinctio repellat mollitia quaerat! Consequuntur, quidem cum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Es lo que buscaba, trataré de adaptarlo para que sea responsive más tarde. Muchas gracias, has sido de gran ayuda.